# Keras model generates Nan on predict on gcp

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform

I have a Keras model (Yolo3) and I want to run the code on several images in the loop:

**I am using Debian 10, Tensorflow 2.4, cuda 11 and K80 Tesla GPU on GCP virtual machine.**

here is the code on colab [code](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/rafikg/d22b21085e2de8d9ae4503055f03aabe/example.ipynb)

I remark that the code is running very well on my local GPU using RTX2070 and tensorflow 2.3

Running exactly the same code on GCP instance  crash at the second iteration by predicting NaN value !!!!)

I debug the image (infinite, Nan value), consider a list of the same image, etc, it still giving the same error!!

I also debug the weights of the model and I get that it has the same weights across iterations!

Anyone from the GCP team can help ?

Comment: Have you tried to file the request to support team via Google Issue [Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)?

Comment: @Nick_Kh, Thanks. I tried to create one but the bottom is grayed!!

Comment: It worth to try then [Create new AI Platform issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187220&template=0), full list for products remains [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list). Is it work for you?

Comment: @Nick_Kh, I put the code if you want to try it